# MySQL query only inserting some data and sorting data

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, primary-key, sql-insert

I have two issues here.  Let me describe the goal of the program first.  I simply want to populate a `company_id` row of my table with 100000 string ids ranging from 00000-99999, shuffled, with no repeats.  I was successful in creating an array like this.  Now, I am trying to fill my primary key column with this array.  As seen in my code below, I am trying to do this with a for loop.  I am new to MySQL, so I am unsure if this is an efficient way to insert an array into a column.  The first issue is that only 1000 strings are entered.  The second issue is that it sorts the strings by number (00000, 00001, etc).  My code is below.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

### Update:

I solved one of the issues.  I was silly enough to think that it would show the table in it's entirety.  I simply went to `MySQLWorkbench > Preferences > SQL Execution > Limit Rows Count`.  Still don't understand why it is automatically sorting my table by primary key.

```
package populateDB;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;

public class PopulateDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] nums = new int[100000];
        String[] ids = new String[100000];

        // Fill array with numbers 0-99999
        for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = i;
        }

        // Fill array to give length
        Arrays.fill(ids, "fill");

        shuffleArray(nums);

        // Changes numbers such as 235 to 00235
        for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            ids[i] = createString(nums[i]);
        }

        try
        {
          // Create a MySQL database connection
          String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
          String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/humansight_schema";
          Class.forName(myDriver);
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "password");

          // The MySQL insert statement
          String query = " insert into user_data (company_id)"
            + " values (?)";
          for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {

            // Create the MySQL insert PreparedStatement
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setString (1, ids[i]);

            // Execute the PreparedStatement
            preparedStmt.execute();

          }
          conn.close();

          System.out.println("Done");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.err.println("Got an exception!");
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void shuffleArray(int[] array)
    {
        int index;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            if (index != i)
            {
                array[index] ^= array[i];
                array[i] ^= array[index];
                array[index] ^= array[i];
            }
        }
    }

    private static String createString(int num) {

        String numString = Integer.toString(num);
        int zeroesToAdd = 5 - numString.length();
        String zeroes = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < zeroesToAdd; i++) {
            zeroes = zeroes.concat("0");
        }

        return zeroes.concat(numString);
    }
}
```

Comment: To shuffle a set of numbers, insert `RAND()` on an indexed column and `SELECT ..  ORDER BY rand_column` when getting results.

Comment: Thanks!  Will do.  But I'm still curious as to why it automatically ordered it--and why it's only inserting 1000.

Comment: Which is the idea behind the suffeling? Why are you using xor (`^`) on the data?

Comment: I need the id's to be randomized.  And the xor is just part of the fisher-yates shuffling algorithm.  The error is not in there.  I know because the array is perfectly fine.  Problems only arise when I try to insert the array.

Comment: After the shuffeling are you sure you don't have duplications? Do you get any exception when running the inserts?

Comment: Yes, I checked.  No exceptions and no duplications.